# Add Drop Shadow to both top and bottom of an UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, quartz-core, dropshadow

I'm trying to add a `drop shadow` to an `UIImageView` so that the drop shadow appears at both the top and bottom of the `UIImageView`.

`imageView.layer.shadowOffset` only does one or the other.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Solved it, by using the `imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0)` adds a drop shadow to top and bottom.